# Add TFS Build status to github

Tags: github, tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I've user Azure portal to setup continuous integration for my Web App. Sources are hosted on GitHub.

When I click GitHub project->Code->Branches, I see build status for master branch:

[image: github screenshot]

All very nice untill now. However, I've manually setup CI build on dev branch in VSTS, but it is not shown in github.

**How do I report build status back to github, so I will see it on dev branch as well?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the piture you posted above, you have pushed 7 commits for master branch, no commits for dev branch. Now you set up a CI build in VSTS to build your project in dev branch. Make sure that Trigger path has set to dev branch correctly in your build definition. Then you push a commit for dev branch, this build definition will be triggered and you will see the build symbol in GitHub.

In addition, the symbol appears only for CI build, if you manually trigger the build VSTS, it doesn't show.

Build definition trigger:

[image]

Build definition repository setting:

[image]

Comment: So github is notified automatically when Repository settings points to GitHub?

Comment: @Liero Yes, I have added a screenshot of the repository settings.